# How to change background color with Qt::BackgroundRole while StyleSheet is present

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets

I am trying to set the background color of a QTableView Item by overwriting data method for Qt::BackgroundRole.

This works **without a StyleSheet**.

But with a qss where I set the QTableView::item border property it does not work.

I need some QTableViews with a general StyleSheet and one QTableView
with the changed backgraound color by Qt::DisplayRole.

- I have tried to seperate my QTableView::item by `setObjectName`: QTableView#SecondView::item.
- I have also tried to remove the StyleSheet from my QTableView by:

  - `m_p_table_view2->setStyleSheet("");`

  or

  - `m_p_table_view2->setStyleSheet(0);`
  - or in StyleSheet with `border: 0;`

But without success.

MyProxyModel  inherits from QStandardItemModel

```
class MyProxyModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
     MyProxyModel(int in_row, int in_col);

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &in_index, int in_role) const override;
};
```

And then i overwrite the data method

```
QVariant MyProxyModel::data(const QModelIndex &in_index, int in_role) const
{
    if(Qt::BackgroundRole == in_role)
    {
        int tmp = QStandardItemModel::data(in_index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();

        switch (tmp)
        {
        case 1:
            return QVariant(QColor(0xBB, 0xFF, 0x99));
            break;
   ...
        default:

            break;
        }
    }

    return QStandardItemModel::data(in_index, in_role);
}
```

It works without stylesheet.

But with StyleSheet it does not work.

```
/*------------------------------------------*/
/*default*/
QTableView
{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #252424;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    outline: 0;
}

QTableView::item
{
/*    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;     */  /* causes the bug */
}

/*------------------------------------------*/
/*second view*/
QTableView#SecondView
{
    background: #99dd99;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    color: #252424;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    outline: 0;
}

QTableView#SecondView::item
{
/*    border: 0;    */                          /* causes the bug too */
}
```